# Azure Text to Speech started returning "400 Bad Request" all the sudden

Tags: azure, azure-cognitive-services

I was using Azure Text-to-Speech API succesfully for months with this format:

```
<speak version='1.0' xmlns='w3.org/2001/10/synthesis' xml:lang='en-US'><voice name='Microsoft Server Speech Text to Speech Voice (fi-FI, HeidiRUS)'>My text</voice></speak>
```

But suddenly this request started returning:

> HTTP/1.1 400 Bad request

We were using the same request successfully for months (with different phrase of course) but just some weeks ago the same request started returning this error. I don't get any additional information so I don't know where to look. Azure documentation says:

> A required parameter is missing, empty, or null. Or, the value passed
>   to either a required or optional parameter is invalid. A common issue
>   is a header that is too long.

I also tried making the request more specific by adding gender and language and replacing single quotes with double quotes, but no use:

```
<speak version="1.0" xmlns="w3.org/2001/10/synthesis" xml:lang="fi-FI" xml:gender="Female"><voice name="Microsoft Server Speech Text to Speech Voice (fi-FI, HeidiRUS)">Text.</voice></speak>
```

Did something change in the API? Or what is missing in my request?

Answer (score 0):

I got a 200 OK with the right content when I send the following payload:

```
<speak version='1.0' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2001/10/synthesis' xml:lang='en-US'><voice name='Microsoft Server Speech Text to Speech Voice (fi-FI, HeidiRUS)'>This is my test</voice></speak>
```

Here is my C# code to send this:

```
// Generate request
string body = $@"<speak version='1.0' xmlns='http://www.w3.org/2001/10/synthesis' xml:lang='{voiceLang}'><voice name='{voiceName}'>{text}</voice></speak>";

using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage())
    {
        // Set the HTTP method
        request.Method = HttpMethod.Post;
        // Construct the URI
        request.RequestUri = new Uri(ttsHostUri);
        // Set the content type header
        request.Content = new StringContent(body, Encoding.UTF8, "application/ssml+xml");
        // Set additional header, such as Authorization and User-Agent
        request.Headers.Add("Authorization", "Bearer " + accessToken);
        request.Headers.Add("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
        // Update your resource name
        request.Headers.Add("User-Agent", "YOUR_RESOURCE_NAME");
        request.Headers.Add("X-Microsoft-OutputFormat", "riff-24khz-16bit-mono-pcm");
        // Create a request
        using (var response = await client.SendAsync(request).ConfigureAwait(false))
        {
            response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

            // Asynchronously read the response
            using (var dataStream = await response.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().ConfigureAwait(false))
            {
                // ... Process your audio here
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The only difference that I can see on our payloads is the `xmlns` value where I have a full url (with http://) whereas yours doesn't get it.

The error may be elsewhere: are you sure you are authenticating yourself when querying the endpoint?

Answer (score 0):

We also suddenly got the 400 error and in our case we had missed to encapsulate the text for the XML request with

> `<![CDATA[ your text here ]]>`

after we did that in our code we got no more reported 400 errors by the users.